# SAP hana hibernate-ogm support documentations and samples

Tags: hibernate, hana, hibernate-ogm, sap-cloud-platform

Hello Experts i am working on connecting hana document store which is no SQL data base shipped as part of hana rdbms ,but could not found any material on its support vi hibernate OGM ,can you please guide me if its possible or any samples available on same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, Hibernate OGM doesn't not support HANA.
[You can use Hibernate ORM](http://in.relation.to/2018/02/08/Introducing-Support-For-SAP-HANA/) instead.

If you still want to create a Hibernate OGM dialect, feel free to ask again in [the Hibernate OGM forum](https://discourse.hibernate.org/c/hibernate-ogm) and I can guide you better there.